# Convert Single Cell reference to Entire Column Reference Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, case

So I have a formula that takes into consideration two other given values in other cells (L:L and K:K) to determine a score. Right now its only working for the specified referenced cells (L2, K2, M2), and I am trying to get it to work for the entire column, instead for only the one.

Here is the VBA code:

```
Sub ExplicitScore()
    If Range("L2").Value = "Healthcare" Then
        Select Case Range("K2").Value
        Case "Executive"
            Range("M2").Value = 60
        Case "IT", "Clinical", "Finance/Revenue Cycle", "Security/Risk/Compliance", "Patient Access/Records"
            Range("M2").Value = 50
        Case "HIM", "Patient Quality/Safety"
            Range("M2").Value = 40
        Case "Pharmacy", "Telecommunications", "Admin"
            Range("M2").Value = 20
        Case Else
            Range("M2").Value = 10
        End Select
    Else
        Select Case Range("K2").Value
         Case "Executive", "IT"
            Range("M2").Value = 10
        Case Else
            Range("M2").Value = 0
        End Select
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You mean you want it to work in L2, K2, M2, then row 3, then row 4, etc. until the first empty row (or some other pre-defined row)?

Comment: Yessir! I have given values in L2, L3...Ln and given values in K2, K3...Kn that serve as the criteria for each row, which should put a result in M2, M3...Mn

Answer (score 0):

A great work around is to create a function, rather than a sub. Set your criteria to variables. Here is the converted code:

```
Function ExScore(Industry, JobCategory)
    If Industry = "Healthcare" Then
        Select Case JobCategory
        Case "Executive"
            ExScore = 60
        Case "IT", "Clinical", "Finance/Revenue Cycle", "Security/Risk/Compliance", "Patient Access/Records"
            ExScore = 50
        Case "HIM", "Patient Quality/Safety"
            ExScore = 40
        Case "Pharmacy", "Telecommunications", "Admin"
            ExScore = 20
        Case Else
            ExScore = 10
        End Select
    Else
        Select Case JobCategory
         Case "Executive", "IT"
            ExScore = 10
        Case Else
            ExScore = 0
        End Select
    End If

End Function
```